# Finding if $\sum \left(1- \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)$ converges

Tags: calculus

I used the comparison test with $\pi^2/n^2$:

$$\lim \frac{1- \cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Since $1/n^2$ converges, so does the given function. Is this correct?

Comment: What does it mean to say that a function converges?

Comment: You are doing convergence of a series?  $\sum(1-\cos(\pi/n))$ ... if so you should say so

Comment: Yes. Another way to see this is to expand cos(x) around 0, hence the 1's subtracted and you are left with the same term which converges. (To be precise, the formulation behind using taylor expansions to test convergence is the comprasion test you just did)

Comment: If you mean does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\cos(\pi/n)\right)$, you can show that $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(x/2)$ then you have that $\sin(y)\leq y$ for all $y\geq 0.$ So you don't need a limit, you have $0<1-\cos(\pi/n)\leq \frac{\pi^2}{n^2}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, fixed

Comment: @GEdgar I wrote that in a rush, sorry, I fixed it now

Comment: I'm confused. I interpreted this as a sequence problem. The sequence with the given term converges to $0$ by elementary means. The argument $\pi/n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and cosine is continuous at $0.$ Since $\cos(0)=1,$ the result follows.

Comment: @ChrisLeary read the edit. It's about the series $\sum(1-\cos(\pi/n)).$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews - Thanks. I completely missed that that one edit was from the OP. I'm OK now.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this lemma is true:

> **Lemma 1:** If $a_n$ is a sequence of positive values such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, and $b_n$ is a sequence such that $\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges.

And thus your limit proves $\sum \left(1-\cos\frac{\pi}n\right)$ converges.

But you can get this slightly more easily by the Lemma:

> **Lemma 2:** $a_n$ is a sequence of positive values such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $b_n$ is a sequence such that $|b_n|\leq a_n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges.

This problem can be solved more directly with lemma 2. First note that $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^{2}\frac{x}{2}$. Since $\sin y\leq y$ for all $y\geq 0$ you have that:

$$0<1-\cos\frac{\pi}{n} = 2\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n}\leq \frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}$$

So if $a_n=\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}$ then $\sum_n a_n$ converges, so, by Lemma 2, if $b_n=1-\cos \frac{\pi}n,$ you get $\sum_n \left(1-\cos\frac{\pi}n\right).$